# boost::time_facet don't formatting the time

Tags: c++, linux, boost, datetime-format

I try to output date with the custom format. For Windows it works fine, but for Linux don't.

```
int main()
{
   const boost::gregorian::date DATE_EPOCH(1970, 1, 1);
   const boost::posix_time::ptime PTIME_DATE_EPOCH(DATE_EPOCH);

   uint64_t time = 1552575540001;  // 14 Mar 2019 14:59:00.001
   using namespace boost::posix_time;
   const ptime posixTime = ptime(PTIME_DATE_EPOCH.date(), milliseconds(time));

   const std::string mask= "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ";

   std::ostringstream stream;
   stream.imbue(std::locale(stream.getloc(), new time_facet(mask.c_str())));
   stream << posixTime;
   std::string timeStr = stream.str();
   std::cout << timeStr;

   return 0;
}
```

But I get 2019-Mar-14 14:59:00.001 instead 2019-03-14T14:59:00.001Z

Could you please help me to find issue.

Comment: I'm getting neither. I get `2019-03-14T14:59:00Z`.

Comment: I try it in wandbox and it works too. And I am pretty sure that it works for many Linux systems, because that code used for several years and problems have not yet been. But I have a test Linux computer on which it does not work. Maybe the problem is in the OS itself?

Comment: Most probably it's something else, like something in the toolchain. Have you tried `std::chrono` instead of using `boost`?

Comment: That is works, but tm hasn't milliseconds, which I needs   

    const std::time_t time = time / 1000;
    tm local;
    localtime_r(&time, &local); // TODO: Check the errors.

    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss.imbue(std::locale::classic());
    oss << std::put_time(&local, mask.c_str());
    return oss.str();

Comment: I don't think you can get only milliseconds. `%f` will give you microseconds. `%s` will give you seconds + microseconds.